# Script to email admin in the event of an attack

Tags: linux, bash, email

I'm using a Script that would automatically do a dump of the attack as soon as it exceeds a threshold. The scripts looks like the following:

```
interface=eth0
dumpdir=/tmp/

while /bin/true; do
  pkt_old=`grep $interface: /proc/net/dev | cut -d :  -f2 | awk '{ print $2 }'`
  sleep 1
  pkt_new=`grep $interface: /proc/net/dev | cut -d :  -f2 | awk '{ print $2 }'`



  pkt=$(( $pkt_new - $pkt_old ))

  echo -ne "\r$pkt packets/s\033[0K"


  if [ $pkt -gt 10000  ]; then
    echo -e "\n`date` Under attack, dumping packets."
    tcpdump -nn -s0 -c 2000 -w $dumpdir/dump.`date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"`.cap
    echo "`date` Packets dumped, sleeping now."
    sleep 300
  fi
done
```

I want the same Script to send an Email to a specified address to notify the Admin if the server was attacked. How should we achieve this?

Comment: man mail: mail -s "Subejct" <Text> <User>

Comment: I tried "echo Hey | mail -s Test Test@mail.com" but nothing was received.

Comment: In /var/mail/mail I got this "    Mailing to remote domains not supported"

Comment: @AsadMoeen Then please delete this question or provide your own answer and mark it as accepted, if you do not it will keep popping to the front page as a open question with no accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did it with the following command.

```
echo Hey | mail -s Test Test@mail.com
```

The above command didn't work so I fixed it by installing sendmail which wasn't installed by default.